# jQuery.post not working within shortcode - Wordpress Ajax

Tags: plugins, ajax

I have a shortcode which works, only thing not working is my ajax callback function, which is not triggered and can't figure out what the error is.

My functions.php for the shortcode and callback function

```
//Insert Referer into DB
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_insert_refer', 'insert_refer_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_insert_refer', 'insert_refer_callback');

function insert_refer_callback() {
//    global $wpdb;
//    $wpdb->insert(
//    'wp_refer',
//  array( 
//      'name' => $_POST['name'],
//        'email' => $_POST['email'],
//      'code' => $_POST['code'] 
//  ));
        global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $whatever = 11;

    $whatever += 10;

        echo $whatever;
    wp_die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}

/** REFER FUNCTION **/
function refer_function ($args){
    $refer_code = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)),0,5);
    $refer_link = "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/refer?friend=".$refer_code;
    $refer = "<div id='refer_one'><h5>Udfyld email og navn, så vi kan skabe dit unikke link.<h5><form method='post' id='refer_one'><input type='text' id='email'  placeholder='Email' name='email'><br/><input type='text' id='name' placeholder='Navn' name='name'><br/><input id='code' type='hidden' value='".$refer_code."' ><input class='sf-button medium blue sf-icon-stroke ansoeg_button' type='submit' value='Videre'></form></div>
    <div id='refer_two' style='display:none'>
    <a href=".$refer_link.">
    ".$refer_link."
    </a>
    </div>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#refer_one').on('submit', function(event) {
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var name =  $('#name').val();
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#refer_one').hide();
            $('#refer_two').css('display','block');
            var data = {
            action: 'insert_refer',
            name: name,
            email: email,
            code: $('#code').val(),
            };
            jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                alert('Got this from the server:');
            });        
            });
    });
    </script>";    
    return $refer;
}

add_shortcode( 'refer', 'refer_function' );
```

Comment: where do you set `ajaxurl`? are you getting any errors in your browser console?

Comment: As I recall , isen't ajaxurl predefined in Wordpress ? - No, no errors in console.log. And if I var_dump(data); I get correct data in the console.log. But I never get anything with the jQuery.post

Comment: ajaxurl is set only when admin bar is on, or in admin area

Comment: How do I add correctly to the frontend then ?

Comment: You need to [localize your script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) and pass into it `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );`

Comment: Correct, that worked.